Why have SIGPIPE when EPIPE exists?
According to pipe(7):

If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process. If the calling process is ignoring this signal, then write(2) fails with the error EPIPE.

Why does Unix need to have the SIGPIPE signal when write() can simply return EPIPE directly? My understanding is that signals are intended for things that are inherently asynchronous (e.g. termination of a child, terminal interrupt). But SIGPIPE is only ever generated as the immediate result of a call to write(), in which case it could always just return EPIPE to to caller to signify the error to the caller.
Why was it deemed necessary to have SIGPIPE in addition to EPIPE?

This goes back to the early days of Unix. Douglas McIlroy, who was the head of the Bell Labs department where Unix was created, and who had worked on other systems including Multics, was very keen on having useful ways to combine programs. As described in The Creation of the UNIX Operating System — Connecting streams like a garden hose:

"If you think about macros," McIlroy explained, "they mainly involve switching data streams. I mean, you're taking input and you suddenly come to a macro call, and that says, 'Stop taking input from here and go take it from there.'

In A Research UNIX Reader: Annotated Excerpts from the Programmer’s Manual, 1971-1986, McIlroy explains that

The appearance of pipes elevated standard-in-standard-out design to the status of a “philosophy” (…)


In one feverish night Ken [Thompson] wrote and installed the pipe system call, added pipes to the shell, and modified several utilities (…), to be usable as filters. (…) Pipes ultimately affected our outlook on program design far more profoundly than had the original idea of redirectable standard input and output.

So the idea of pipelines came first, and the pipe system call was a way of implementing it. Pipelines appeared in Unix v3. Before that, chaining programs together required using a temporary file for the first program's output, passing it as input to the second program, and finally removing the temporary file.
Now, if your philosophy of programs is that they are meant to consume input and produce output, what do you do if a program's output stops being consumed? The program is not useful any longer, so you kill it. Hence what evolved into the SIGPIPE signal. Because some programs have useful behavior that goes beyond writing content to standard output, they can request not to get killed if their standard output goes away. Such programs observe an EPIPE error. But because pipes are such a fundamental tool, getting killed is the default behavior.

Some programmers don’t bother to check for errors. 
Some programs generate large amounts of output with printf
(or, perhaps, write) without checking for an error return. 
Such a program could pointlessly run until completion,
with output going to the bit bucket, if it is writing to a broken pipe.
SIGPIPE forces such a program to terminate
(assuming it doesn’t catch or ignore the signal).

Another thing is that a program that did check the errors but wasn't explicitly aware  of EPIPE might deal with it by printing an error message and dying. But the signal kills the program before it gets to do that, and while the shell sees the program died of a signal, it's more likely to know what's going on and not print anything. This way, you usually don't see "Broken pipe" errors for pipelines, even if the right-hand side exits early. You might get one if SIGPIPE is ignored, e.g. something like (trap "" PIPE; cat file.txt | head -1).

Looking at this a bit differently, SIGPIPE is there for sensible ‘default behavior’ in a shell. EPIPE is there for things that need non-default handling of pipes.

Notoriously, Python programs fail noisily when connected to a broken pipe.

EPIPE is an inband error from write that occurs on orderly shutdown of the pipe.  The process typically doesn't die from this and gets to continue, hopefully after handling the error and before trying to write more data.  If it ignores the error instead of handling it and continues writing to the shutdown pipe, it will get a SIGPIPE and die.
Also, SIGPIPE is, as you say, an asynchronous signal that typically occurs when the pipe is ended suddenly without a clean shutdown.  For instance, if the process on the other end of the pipe exits without reading data already in flight, after the write for that data has already returned.  If SIGPIPE is not trapped, it typically causes the receiving process to be killed.
A typical use case would be a process outputing data that is sent to less.  If you press q in less, the generating process would get a SIGPIPE.
$ strace yes | less
:write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = 8192
[...]
) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1532747, si_uid=500} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++


What exactly is the difference between a clean/orderly shutdown of a pipe and an unclean one? Do you have any references for this?

try man close and man 2 shutdown  but note that getting EPIPE or not is an easy race condition.  (Maybe man pipe too)

So you can't point to any specific part of those documents? I don't see any mentions of SIGPIPE or EPIPE in at least the Linux man page for close(2), and AFAIU, shutdown(2) is only for sockets. The man page refers to "full-duplex connections", which pipes are not.

The pipe(7) man page says "If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process. If the calling process is ignoring this signal, then write(2) fails with the error EPIPE.", i.e. it's the same situation that causes both; there's no mention of clean or unclean shutdowns there, so it's quite hard to find out what the distinction would be. And in fact, you seem to say exactly the opposite to the man page in that first paragraph, wrt. which of the two needs to be ignored to get the other.

@ilkkachu  While shutdown(2) is only for sockets, EPIPE and SIGPIPE are also used for sockets.
